# Down Vote Unicorn Animation Refund Request

Tags: support, unicoins

Hello Sir Stroke Madam,

When I Buy Unicorn Animation Pack For Ninety Nine (99) Unicoins I Expect Joyful Colorful Animations of Unicorns When I Vote Post. When I Vote Bad Post Down I Get Horse With Fake Cheap Plastic Imitate Of Horn Instead. Horse Throws Fake Cheap Plastic Imitate of Horn At Score Count. [View Discreet Advise.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RXgxY.png)

Everybody Know True Unicorn Horn Not Removable. Removing Unicorn Horn Kills Unicorn. Unicorn Brain Extends All The Way Into Horn. Here See Picture.

[image]

Even If Unicorn Unlikely Survival He No Longer Unicorn, Just Horse. Plus In This Case Animation Is Dismember. Children Scarred For Life. PETA Will Involve.

Please To Refund

Yours True

P. Bad

Poster Script: Can Has Refund In Bacon Form?

Comment: I honestly wish one of the Unicoin powers was being able to both up and down vote posts. This is simultaneously incredible and horrible.

Comment: BTW, nice art.. you have a good future as painter. good luck.

Comment: @Mr_Green Thank Sir I Exercise ART Very Hard

Comment: Pretty sure we had the same complaint in 2011, but I can't find it now.

Comment: @balpha Repeat Offense? Want Threeful Refund Now.

Comment: Lol I liked the shape of the brain

Comment: Possibly duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549641/how-to-capitalize-the-first-letter-of-each-word-in-a-string-python

Comment: @codemonkey Sir I Lovingive Uppercase Each Of Important Words Manual. It Just So Happen All Words Importants.

Comment: Has Been Thirty Minute Now Still No Reply From Stroke Madam. Disappoint.